# How to keep cursors in v$sql_plan alive longer

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-execution-plan

I'm trying to analyse a query execution plan in my Oracle database. I have set

```
alter system set statistics_level = all;
```

Such that I can compare estimated cardinalities and times with actual cardinalities and times. Now, I'm running this statement in order to display that information.

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(
    sql_id => '6dt9vvx9gmd1x', 
    cursor_child_no => 2, 
    FORMAT => 'ALLSTATS LAST'));
```

But I keep getting this message

```
NOTE: cannot fetch plan for SQL_ID: 6dt9vvx9gmd1x, CHILD_NUMBER: 2 
      Please verify value of SQL_ID and CHILD_NUMBER; 
      It could also be that the plan is no longer in cursor cache (check
      v$sql_plan)
```

The `CHILD_NUMBER` was correct when the query was being executed. Also, when I run `dbms_xplan.display_cursor` at the same time as the query, I get the actual plan. But my JDBC connection closes the `PreparedStatement` immediately after execution, so maybe that's why the execution plan disappears from `v$sql_plan`.

Am I getting something wrong, or how can I analyse estimated/actual values after execution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Increase the shared_pool to create more caching space for the cursors.
If in 11g, capture the sql plan in the baselines using optimizer_capture_sql_plan_baselines. This stores the plans in dba_sql_plan_baselines.

Answer (score 5):

You could always pin the cursor, which is new in 11g -

```
dbms_shared_pool.keep ('[address, hash_value from v$open_cursor]', 'C');
```

Comment: Very nice, I didn't know that. And I guess you'll have to manually throw it out again using `dbms_shared_pool.purge` ?

Comment: Yup.  Or shut down the instance.  It won't repin it automatically.

Comment: Ah, I guess I'll prefer the `purge` rather than shutting it down :)